# How do I calculate median with tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

People usually propose to use **tf.contrib.distributions.percentile**, but it gives an exception now:

```
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
```

how can I calculate median without downgrading TF version?

Answer (score 3):

It's now in the separate module, TensorFlow Probability (TFP), and it's called [tfp.stats.percentile](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile?hl=en). It also seem absent in compat module.

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability